# Translation in public site for Guest User

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, force.com-sites

In salesforce public site I have to provide 3 links for translations (let's say Eng/Fin/Swe) and when user click into it i want to translate the whole page accordingly. As in public site, page context runs on the public User's Locale so i can't hndle translations via translation workbench .

Please suggest how can I achieve this by using Google apis or etc in Public site Vf page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quickly using Google translate.

1. Go to below URL : https://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=en-GB
2. Enter your website name and adress
3. Google will generate a code snippet. The code will add translate button. This will allow users to tranlate site into language preferred by them.++

[image]